# How to keep my position:fixed navbar from appearing underneath other elements?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a problem at the css levels because I am testing the code via this site:
https://codepen.io/steveeeie/pen/NVWMEM . It works very well but at the level of my `navbar`, it goes above and not below when I scroll.

I noticed it's because of `position: absolute` but i'm trying to change it but it makes my navbar not fix at all at the top when scrolling.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Hi sakura, you should split your question into two distinct questions, as the second question you are asking isn't really related to the code issue.

Comment: yes sorry that's correct I should have formulated it in just 1 question, thank you

Comment: Hi sakura, is it the right codepen? I'm not seeing the navbar or anything related to it. Also, try including the code here instead of linking, so that we don't have to go to another site to look at your code.

Comment: This code comes from this site originally and I'm trying to include it where I already put a already made navbar and a footer

Comment: I don't see any relevant code in your link. You should post the code here and then perhaps we can help :).

Comment: sorry, i had sent the code but it was deleted for me: /, justin's answer to solve my problem, thanks to you for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to as a CSS `level` is actually called the `z-index` of an element.
You can read up on it here: [z-index on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

From MDN:

> The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one.

The gist of it is that because your navbar (presumably) comes before these cards in your markup it will be shown underneath the cards. To combat this, set the `z-index` on the navbar to a value that is higher than the cards. Like so:

```css
.navbar {
  /* [your other styles for your navbar] */

  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer to perfectly solve my problem! thank you ! :)

(I can not vote your answer because lack of reputation point)

Comment: No worries, marking it as correct boosts my reputation plenty. Glad I could help!